# Proof of linear transformation $\mathbb{\tilde{L}}(u)=\mathbb{L}(u)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm working on linear transformation and trying to answer :

Let $E$ and $F$ be two vector spaces on $\mathbb{K}$, $E$ is finite. $V \ \subset E$ a subvector space of E. $L \ \in \mathbb{L}(V,F)$ (linear transformation from V to F).
Prove there is $\tilde{L} \ \in \mathbb{L}(E,F)$ such as $\forall \ u \ \in \ V, \mathbb{\tilde{L}}(u)=\mathbb{L}(u)$

I have tried using the definition of linear transformation but do not find the way to prove it.
Thank you

Comment: Let $E=V+W$ and $V\cap W=0$. There is a linear transform, whichs kernel contains $W$, and acts on $V$ like $L$.

Answer (score 2):

If we work with finite-dimensioned $E$, then all you need is to follow the steps

1. Find a basis $\{e_i\} $in $V$.
2. Extend it to a basis on the whole space - say, you find those missing basis vectors $v_j$.
3. Define $\tilde L (e_i)= L(e_i)$ and $\tilde L(v_j)=0$.
4. Conclude.

Comment: How could I find the basis {e_i} in V ?

Comment: @Tom75 here you don't need to find this basis explicitely - it is sufficient to know that the basis exists.